# I am using open FDA for the first time, How can I get API key?

Tags: api, openfda

We are using Composite data virtualisation tool.

How can openFDA help us?

How can I get API key?

Answer (score 2):

You can query the openFDA API without a key, but for more requests, you can freely request one.

The screenshots below come from this **[Reference Page](https://open.fda.gov/api/reference/)**.

[image]

To get a key, you register with your email address on this screen

[image]